# Using excel, how do you calculate the average occurrence of the same numbers in a column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average

For example:

[Column A] 1,1,2,2,3,3,3 = The average is 2.3

[Column B] 2,2,3,3,4,4 = the average is 2 (each number appears 2 times each)

[Column C] 2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4 = the average is 3 (each number appears 3 times each)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=(ROWS(A1:A9)-COUNTBLANK(A1:A9))/SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(OFFSET(A1,,,COUNTA(A1:A9));OFFSET(A1,,,COUNTA(A1:A9))))
```

The lenght of the different columns makes it a bit tricky though(hence using OFFSET and COUNTA).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With array formula it will be simpler:

```
=COUNT(A$1:A$10)/SUM(IF(A$1:A$10<>"",1/(COUNTIF(A$1:A$10,A$1:A$10))))
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another option (with blank cells support):

```
=AVERAGE(COUNTIF(C5:C13,UNIQUE(C5:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(COUNTA(C5:C13)+ROW(C4),COLUMN(C4))))))
```

Output (French software, O365) :

[image: Count]

Comment: Thank you for the help. Just curious, why is there a comma instead of a period (or point)? EX: 2,3 instead of 2.3

Comment: Because french version of Excel uses comma by default.